# getting String from ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I am getting data from database and putting it into a array.Array contain CODE (int) and DESCRIPTION (String).Code is in the gridview and i want that if someone clicks on a code then realted description should be shown in a new activity.i have used OnItemclicklistener but dont know how to get only String from the array to show it on a new activity. "i want that the code from arraylist should be printed on first screen and when clicked description ll be printed in new activity as textview"

```
 private void show_data() {
    final GridView gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
  //  final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    final Database_handler db = new Database_handler(this);
    Cursor cur = db.fetchAllData();
    final ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            array_list.add(cur.getString(0));
            array_list.add(cur.getString(1));
        } while (cur.moveToNext());
    }
    final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_list);
   // listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    gv.setAdapter(adapter);

    gv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
                    /*SOME CODE*/ }
```

This is Stablearrayadapter class

```
   public class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
 HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
        mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
    }
}
```

XML class

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView_descrip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
```

activty for description

```
 public class desc_view extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    setContentView(R.layout.desc_view);
   /* try {
        Intent recv = getIntent();
        ArrayList<String> array_list_recvd = recv.getStringArrayListExtra("array_list2");
        int intValue = recv.getIntExtra("intVariableName", 0);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_descrip);
        tv.setText(array_list_recvd.get(intValue));
        setContentView(tv);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Error Second :", e.toString());
    }*/
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use arraylist of `Map<String,String>`

```
 ArrayList<Map<String,String>> array_list = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        Map<String,String> map=new HashMap<String,String>();
        map.put("code",cur.getString(0));
        map.put("desc",cur.getString(1));

        array_list.add(map);

    } while (cur.moveToNext());
}
```

**and on itemClick**

```
String desc=list.get(position).get("desc");
```

Comment: try to print data in cursor do...while loop may be it null and check are you using right arraylist